# python how to split a string and rejoin it

Tags: python, string, replace

I am doing a cryptography assignment in python and I need to:
- split a string
- replace the letters
- rejoin it so that it is one word.

This is the full code but I am stuck on the for loop under `def encode(plain)`.

```
""" crypto.py
Implements a simple substitution cypher
"""

alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
key =   "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV"

def menu():

    print("Secret decoder menu")
    print("0) Quit")
    print("1) Encode")
    print("2) Decode")
    print("What do you want to do?")
    response = input()
    return response

def encode(plain):

for i in range(len(plain)):

    plain = plain.upper()
    x = plain[i:i+1]
    y = alpha.index(x)
    z = key[y:y+1]
    plain[x] = z

return plain

def main():

keepGoing = True
  while keepGoing:

    response = menu()

    if response == "1":

        plain = input("text to be encoded: ")
        print(encode(plain))

    elif response == "2":
       coded = input("code to be decyphered: ")
       print (decode(coded))

    elif response == "0":
       print ("Thanks for doing secret spy stuff with me.")
       keepGoing = False

    else:
       print ("I don't know what you want to do...")

return main

main()
menu()
```

Comment: Sample input and expected output would be nice.

Comment: you need to indent the code under your function definitions

Comment: Secret decoder menu
0) Quit
1) Encode
2) Decode
What do you want to do?
1
text to be encoded: hello
L
T
Z
Z
E
HELLO

Comment: this is what happens when I print out z, I want it to come out as one word though

Comment: I have the code indented in idle but it got messed up copying and pasting to here

Comment: It seems to me like a Caesar cipher, here is a way to split a string
>>> string = "hello"
>>> individual_characters = [i for i in string]
>>> individual_characters
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>> 
and here is a way to rejoin them 
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>> new_string =  ''.join(individual_characters) # 2single quotes dont get me wrong
>>> new_string
'hello'

Comment: Use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) with [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to implement this substitution is to use dictionary and list comprehension:

```
alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
key = "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV"
converter = {a:b for a, b in zip(alpha, key)}
def encode(s):
   return ''.join(converter[i] for i in s)

def decode(s):
   reverse = {b:a for a, b in converter.items()}
   return ''.join(reverse[i] for i in s)

def main():
   response = input("Enter 1 to decode, 2 to encode: ")
   if response == "1":
      the_string = input("Enter the scrambled string: ")
      print("The result is ", decode(the_string))
   elif response == "2":
       the_string = input("Enter the plain string: ")
       print("The result is ", encode(the_string))
main()
```

Comment: In your code, `reverse` ends up the same as `converter`. I would use `converter=dict(zip(alpha,key))` and `reverse=dict(zip(key,alpha))` (or `reverse={b:a for a, b in converter.items()}`).

Comment: @MatthiasFripp thank you for pointing that out. Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to implement your own solution do as @Ajax1234 say.

But is more easy with [string translate](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_translate.htm)

```
alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
key =   "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV"
crypto = maketrans(alpha, key)

....
the_string = input("Enter the scrambled string: ")
the_string = the_string.upper()
encrypted = the_string.translate(crypto)
```

Comment: my professor told us to only use standard code so we can't use the translate() method. We also can't change the main() function so we basically have to convert the secret messages using string manipulation. Under def encode(plain) I already sliced the string "plain" and compared the characters to the strings "alpha" and "key" but I don't know how to combine them into a word again